# How to modify this batch script to delete oldest subfolders instead of files in a directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-management

The following batch file can be invoked by running `limitdirsize.bat c:\example 4000000` to limit `C:\example` to 4GB. It works well when dealing with a folder containing only files.

When run, it deletes the oldest files in the directory until the size of the folder is 4GB.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a targetsize=%2
call :foldersize %1
for /F "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /A-D /OD /B %1\*.*') do (
  if !sz! geq !targetsize! (
    call :filesize %1\%%F
    del %1\%%F
    set /a sz = !sz! - !kb!
  ) else (
    echo Done... %1 size is now !sz! KB
    goto :eof
  )
) 
echo Not completely done... %1 size is still !sz! KB 
goto :eof  

:filesize
set /a kb = %~z1 / 1024
goto :eof

:foldersize
set sz=0
for %%F in (%1\*.*) do (
  set /a kb = %%~zF / 1024
  set /a sz = !sz! + !kb!  
)
goto :eof
```

I would like to limit the size of a directory which contains only subdirectories.

The batch script for determining subdirectory size would be

```
:foldersizerecurse
set sz=0
for /F %%F in ('dir /OD /B *.*') do (
  set /a kb = %%~zF / 1024
  set /a sz = !sz! + !kb!  
  echo %%F %%~zF !kb! !sz!
)
goto :eof
```

According to the author of this code:

> you need to pipe the 'dir /S' command output to sort and sort by date

For clarity: `:foldersize` calculates the size of the folder being cleaned, and everything between line 4 and that function is for recognizing older files and deleting them until the desired size of the directory is reached.

Comment: So, what do you want us to do then?

Comment: I was hoping someone might know how to modify this script so that it would delete subfolders inside of a directory, as it only deletes files in the root of a directory at this time. So if `C:\example` were being limited to 4GB, and the oldest file was `C:\example\subfolder1\file.ext` and deleting it would put `C:\example` back under 4GB, then the script would delete `C:\example\subfolder`

Comment: Start from scratch with `for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /B /s /a:-D %1\') do @echo %%~tG€%%~zG€%%~G` substituting the `€` character with any character not appearing in your file names. Then replace `%%~tG` with something in the `yyyymmddHHmmss` pattern. Redirect `echo` to a temporary file, `sort` this file in ascending order... **Caveat**: ensure `%1` does not extend the scope overly (consider e.g. `limitdirsize.bat "" 4000000` call will attempt to cleanse all the script current drive)